# android: call javascript from java problem

Tags: java, javascript, android

I want to know if there is way to call javascript from java on android?
In my program, I interact java and javascript together. I am using java to receive response(json data) from TCP server and save them into a file. In webview I am using javascript jQuery getJSON() function to retrieve that file and using jQuery plot chart library to draw chart. Now, there is no relationship between java and javascript. Every time when I update data and file, I still need to click a button in webview to trigger the draw function. I want the programmes to be smart and handy. Is that a way to call or execute javascript from java. I know one way:

```
Button update = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.write('hello')");
            }
        });
```

But the problem is I already do a index page by loadurl().

```
final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkankan);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

When I trigger this click event, all contents were gone only a string "hello" there. Another thing is why I need to change webview's type to final to avoid eclipse error. Does this is the problem to trigger my main problem? If so, how can I fix it?
Thanks for you patience. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance you have a `javascript` method in the `index.html` called `loadData()` which reads the file you saved in the `java`, then what you can do is `wv.loadUrl("javascript:loadData()");`. This actually call the `javascript` method and you can then read the file in that method. Hope this solves your problem.

or in simple terms. jus do this `webView.loadUrl("javascript:jsmethodname()");` to execute javascript from java.

Comment: I dont't quite understand how to do that. Could you show me an example?

Comment: You said that you are downloading json and saving that to a file using java. so when the json downloading/ saving the to file is completed you can do this `wv.loadUrl("javascript:getJSON()");` makes sense. this is very much simple.

Comment: @Varun Hi, I try your advice but still not works .. can you help me with my problem? Here is question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633793/call-javascript-function-from-android-activity-class

Answer (score 0):

You can try to communicate java with javascript registering a java object to the webview that is executing the javascript.

The method addJavascriptInterface from Webview will allow you to make available a Java object to the Javascript scope, something like this:

```
WebView mWebView = new WebView(mContext);
//... webview initialization, js enabling etc.
MyProxyObject obj = new MyProxyObject(); //This object can interchange just basic types, but Strings are basic types
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(obj,"myproxyobj");
```

With that code what you will have in the Javascript context you will have an object 'myproxyobj' that is actually a Java object.

Remember, you can interchange just basic types.

For more info check the following url:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Specially check the section: Binding JavaScript code to Android code

Cheers,
Francisco

Comment: You have the problem the wrong way around. He wants to call javascript from java, not call java from javascript.