# Is it possible to use HTML to submit some data and read it in android application?

Tags: android, html

That means, suppose i am writing a string, then submit it using a click button in HTML. Is it possible to retrieve it from my Android Phone Application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to use the Java/JavaScript bridge from Android. You can publish your data from the webview layer and get a Java method invoked on a registered Java object.

Here is a tutorial to see how this works: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/JavascriptBridge

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of OpenMobster and I wrote this tutorial

Thanks

Comment: thank sir, i don't know whether it is helpful to me since i have no idea over this problem, i have to have a try on them first

Comment: this is all under local android phone? what i want is there maybe a server side sending some string remotely, and the client get it from android phone, is it possible?

Comment: yes that is possible. You can fetch the value from the server and then invoke the Java object from the HTML/JavaScript layer

Comment: is this similar to your link above? Since I am not quite understand about how this work. That means, i don't understand how Android phone are able to wait for the server side (which is not local) to fetch the value. Then the Android are able to detect it and the execute the remaining code to show the value. Is it just simply replace the "file:///android_asset/html/index.html" to my HTML URL?

Comment: Also in the other direction, you can fetch the server side data in your Java layer (native code) and then invoke your JavaScript with the new data fetched from the server. The 'loadUrl' method does that magic. See this thread for more details on this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870490/android-call-javascript-from-java-problem

Comment: No the link above only does local communication between the two layers. Key is really to understand the communication between the two layers. Where the data comes from (remote,local) etc is the easy part.This does not replace your index.html URL. The way this waits is because an invocation from the JavaScript layer to the native layer is synchronous. In this call you fetch the data and return the result. Although blocking the UI to fetch remote data is not a good practice. You should fetch the data in the background and store it locally. Then the call would read the data locally

Comment: Yes, but i want to do something asynchronous. That means there two people apart from each other. One using the HTML form to submit some data. And the other one can read it from his Android phone. Therefore it is asynchronous. But i think the link above is synchronous

Comment: yes, i understand your point. But the first thing is how can accept the data send from HTML form?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly then here is what you may need. 1) Submit the HTML form from HTML/JavaScript layer to a server, 2) Push this update from the server to the native layer. So now data is send from the HTML layer and its pushed from the server to the native Java layer. Is this correct?

Comment: cool. here is an alternative method if you want to avoid server push (non-trivial to do). 1>Submit HTML Form to the server, 2>Make a notification request from JavaScript to Java Layer (the link covers this part), 3> In the Java layer, return quickly and spawn a background thread to pull the appropriate data from the server. This is the pull approach which is easier and cleaner to implement. Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use WebView's *addJavascriptInterface* to interface HTML & Java, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)